# Is there an advantage to declaring a private method "final" in Java?

Tags: java

Is there an advantage to declaring a private method as "final" in Java?

If my understanding is correct, the "final" Modifier makes sure I cannot override a method in a subclass and so this *may* make this method more efficient during runtime. Some literature says it can be inlined if it is final for example which may make the method call faster. Also, the Java runtime won't have to go look for other method in the inheritance hierarchy if it is declared final.

However, private functions cannot be overriden, so are they implicitly "final" as well? Is there a difference between the following two declarations:

```
private void myFun()
```

and

```
private final void myFun();
```

Comment: Why the [tag:c++] tag? I've deleted it as I see absolutely no relevance to your question.

Comment: `final` on a property != `final` on a method. Final properties mean they can't be modified; period.

Comment: yes realized the distinction as soon as I clicked post, changed the question now to only ask about functions. Thanks.

Comment: @mohsaied aaand, there are no "functions" in Java. Let's be correct and call that "methods"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclasses may not override `private` methods by design. Furthermore, the `final` keyword tells the compiler that subclasses may not override a method regardless of its access level.

Since `private` already implies that a subclass may not override a method, declaring a private method to be `final` is redundant. Making the declaration won't cause problems, but it won't accomplish anything either, since privates are automatically considered final.

All compilers will treat `private` methods as `final`. The compiler will not allow any `private` method to be overridden. Likewise, all compilers will prevent subclasses from overriding `final` methods.

**Update**

In your question you're saying

> the "final" Modifier makes sure I cannot override a method in a
>   subclass and so makes this method *more efficient during runtime*

This is quite a questionable statement. If you declare your `private` method `final`, the optimization will depend on the compiler you are using and it's settings. That means *NO*. No, it's not necessarily true that if you do declare your method `private` and `final`, or just `final`, it would run faster.

Comment: Java doesn't have compilers with different optimization settings. They leave optimization up to the JVM.

Comment: @Boann, how about `javac`, `GCJ` or `ECJ`?

Comment: @Boann http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981460/optimization-by-java-compiler

Comment: @Boann, GCJ docs: `When the optimization level is greater or equal to "-O2", gcj will try to optimize the way calls into the runtime are made to initialize static classes upon their first use (this optimization isn't carried out if "-C" was specified.) When compiling to native code, "-fno-optimize-static-class-initialization" will turn this optimization off, regardless of the optimization level in use.`

Answer (score 4):

No, the final keyword is unnecessary for private methods.
Per definition, there is no difference between **private** and **private final**.
For more information, see ['final methods'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

These are the different meanings and advantages of `final` in Java :

- The final keyword on a primitive type variable makes it a constant impossible to reassign. the interest is obvious.
- The final keyword on an object variable prevents its reference from being changed.
- The final keyword on a method prevents it from being overrided in a subclass. It is useful to protect the functionality of a critical method the superclass while letting the subclasses see it.
- The final keyword on a class prevents it from being extended by another class. It is most of the time a bad idea but many base classes of the standard library are like this (for example `java.lang.Math`, `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.Integer`...)

As you can see, declaring some method both `private` and `final` is equivalent to declaring it as simply `private` because in both cases, subclass won't be able to override it.

However, there is a difference for a variable. Indeed, declaring it `private` will only hide it to other classes whereas adding `final` will also prevents its reference from being changed in the code of the current class (an will force the constructors to initialize it).

Comment: Then what is the point of having a final private method? It is not like subclasses can see private (without final!) methods

Comment: Only point 3 is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Adam But it is potentially helpful to future readers to show that `final` has different meanings in different contexts in java.

Comment: @MattCoubrough but yet you have not really answered the question; is there any point to adding final to private methods?

Comment: @codequestioneer I did not mention such methods, at the contrary, I said final enabled to let a method being seen by the subclasses yet not risking them to alter its behaviour

Comment: @MattCoubrough Really?? if they happened to stumble on a question titled, "Is there an advantage to declaring a private method “final” in Java?"

Comment: @Dici still unclear if and why I would want to use "private final" on a method. Perhaps it doesn't make any difference and it is just a redundancy that the language permits?

Comment: @Adam Hum I just saw "private" in the title.

Comment: @codequestioneer I haven't answered the question because it is a duplicate and I voted up the comment flagging it as such: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1985183/3651800

Comment: @Dici Apologies, I believe the question has been rewritten since you started answering it.

Comment: @Adam We cannot predict what edits the poster will make to the title of his question after he posts it

Comment: @MattCoubrough I havent seen it else, but you have your point. No worries :)

Comment: I edited my answer so that it answers better to the edited question (I hope)